# Referencing a TV show in LaTeX (overleaf) [APA]

Tags: bibtex, apa-style

I'm trying to reference a TV Show in APA-style in LaTeX (overleaf), using apacite and natbibapa. I guess the writer and director should be placed as Authors in my bib.tex file.

Where should I put the writer and director of the tv-show? And Which @ should I use? I'm not sure if it should be @misc or not.

```
@misc{psycho,
author = {writer_name, director_name}
publisher = {BNNVARA},
title = {{De Psycho Show - Waarom hebben we persoonlijke ruimte?}},
url = {https://www.bnnvara.nl/depsychoshow/artikelen/waarom-hebben-we- 
persoonlijke-ruimte},
year = {2019}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The term "APA style" is not very precise and there's more than one bibliography style file that purports to implement "APA style". Are you maybe thinking of the `apacite` package and bibliography style, which implement the guidelines of the 6th edition of the APA style manual? Please advise.

Comment: Thanks, I did edit my question and add indeed apacite (and natbibapa).

Comment: For the `apacite` bibliography style, it would indeed seem appropriate to use the `@misc` entry type, as there's no other obvious candidte entry type. I'm afraid I'm quite unfamiliar with bibliography- and citation-related conventions for TV shows. E.g., is it customary to mention both writer(s) and director(s)? What about the TV station on which the show first aired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this guide on the APA style guide](https://www.citefast.com/styleguide.php?style=APA&sec=Television), I would write it in the .bib file as follows:

```
@misc{psycho,
author = {WriterName, W. W. {\relax (Writer)} and DirectorName, D. D. {\relax (Director)}},
address = {[Television broadcast] City},
publisher = {BNNVARA},
title = {{De Psycho Show - Waarom hebben we persoonlijke ruimte?}},
url = {https://www.bnnvara.nl/depsychoshow/artikelen/waarom-hebben-we-persoonlijke-ruimte},
year = {2019}
}
```

The `\relax` things in the `author` field ensure that those things in between brackets appear correctly in the References list (don't get shortened to a single letter like first names would), but do not appear in in-text citations.

I added `[Television broadcast]` to the `address` field because this also results in correct formatting -- it should go after the show's title, but not in italics. You'll also want to add the name of the city here (I guess the city in which the publisher is located), as well as the state if it's from a US broadcast (but I see in this case it's a Dutch broadcast, so should be no need to include anything like a state).